# Ajax not always being called

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Ok so I have a button 'up' which when pressed starts a countdown from 8 and when it reaches 0 an ajax call to update.php is made which in turn updates an sql table. update.php is working.

```
 <input type='button' id='countdw' value='Wait 8s'  class='btn btn-primary disabled'>
```

This is working, just not each time the countdown reaches 0. This bit of code doesn't seem to execute each time

```
$.ajax({
        url: "update.php",
```

Here is the code

```
<script>
                var secsLeft = 8;
                setInterval(function(){
                    secsLeft--;
                    if(secsLeft > 0){
                        $('#countdw').val('Wait ' + secsLeft + 's');
                    } else if(secsLeft == 0){
                        $('#countdw').removeClass('disabled');
                        $('#countdw').val('UP');
                        $('#countdw').attr("onclick","myfunction()");

                    }
                }, 1000);        
            </script>

            <script>
                count=0;
                function myfunction(){
                    if(mycount!=0 && mycount%25==0){

                    }else{
                            var secsLeft = 8;
                            setInterval(function(){
                                secsLeft--;
                                if(secsLeft > 0){
                                    $('#countdw').addClass('disabled');
                                    $('#countdw').val('Wait ' + secsLeft + 's');
                                } else if(secsLeft == 0){
                                    $('#countdw').removeClass('disabled');
                                    $('#countdw').val('UP');
                                    $('#countdw').attr("onclick","myfunction()");

                                    $.ajax({
                                url: "update.php", 
                                data:{'user':'<?php echo $subid ?>','data':'<?php echo $key ?>'},
                                success: function(result){

                                }
                            });

                                }
                            }, 1000);

                    }
                    up();
                }
            </script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what part isn't working. The PHP script or the AJAX?

Comment: Did you debug to see where it stops processing?

Answer (score 2):

**Less-or-equal**

```
# instead of
#     if(secsLeft == 0){
# test if it's less-or-equal zero
if(secsLeft <= 0){
```

In JavaScript events sometimes pile up, and then race conditions occur, which seem to be unlikely. In your case it could be that `secsLeft` is decreased two times, before it's checked for equality.

**Was a request sent?**

Make sure the AJAX request isn't sent. There are developer tools for every browser, where you can check all out going traffic. Make sure there is no error messages as response to your AJAX request.

Besides that you should add `console.log(..)` to the `success()` and `error()` funtions of `$.ajax` to see if something is happening behind the curtain.

**What's happening afterwards?**

You're calling a method `up()`. Make sure this method doesn't prevent your AJAX call, for example by triggering a redirect.

Comment: Well well it was the update.php, but thank you for suggesting the developer tools. I just installed/used firebug and it helped me find the problem. I tried the secLeft <=0 and it made the button flash on and off and called the update.php several times. Cheers again.

Comment: Often we can only point into some direction, although the solution is something else. :-)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i want you to forgive my english language. I can't really get your preoccupation but when see your code, what is the role of variable `mycount` and where is it defined? when `setInterval()` is running with the first script block, `secsLeft` will always continous to be decreased. So each time `secsLeft` will be `<= 0` you will have instructions in the "*else*" block which will be executed and maybe it's not the desired result. This can be optimized by stopping the timed function when `secsLeft<=0`. Then you will have something like that:

```
 <script>
            var secsLeft = 8;
            var timedDecreaseID = setInterval(function(){
                secsLeft--;
                if(secsLeft > 0){
                    $('#countdw').val('Wait ' + secsLeft + 's');
                } else { //secsLeft <= 0
                    $('#countdw').removeClass('disabled');
                    $('#countdw').val('UP');
                    $('#countdw').attr("onclick","myfunction()");

                    clearInterval( timedDecreaseID );//will stop this timed function
                }
            }, 1000);        
        </script>
```

In the second script block there can be a "*collision*" between the `setInterval` which is implemented and the previous other in the first script block. This also explain why i recommend to stop the first one after the associated condition is realised. Another remark is that if you make the test `secsLeft <=0` you will have an ajax call each time `secsLeft` will be decrease under value `0`, and this will always happen if the considered `setInterval` call is not stopped. So, unless is the desired result, i think is better to do something like:

```
<script>
            count=0;
            function myfunction(){
                if(mycount!=0 && mycount%25==0){

                }else{
                        var secsLeft = 8;
                        timedDecreaseID = setInterval(function(){
                            secsLeft--;
                            if(secsLeft > 0){
                                $('#countdw').addClass('disabled');
                                $('#countdw').val('Wait ' + secsLeft + 's');
                            } else {//secsLeft <= 0
                                $('#countdw').removeClass('disabled');
                                $('#countdw').val('UP');
                                $('#countdw').attr("onclick","myfunction()");

                                $.ajax({
                            url: "update.php", 
                            data:{'user':'<?php echo $subid ?>','data':'<?php echo $key ?>'},
                            success: function(result){

                            }
                        });

                        clearInterval( timedDecreaseID );//will stop this timed function
                            }
                        }, 1000);

                }
                up();
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I have implemented this as yes it does make sense although my original code did seem to work ok it was just the update.php which had the problem. 1 thing I noticed is that setInterval runs extremely slow using Chrome, perhaps it's just me? but my countdown is pretty jolty usings my code and your amended version.  Do you know of any reason why? perhaps it's just me.

Comment: Depending on user's cpu usage, process can take time to run. Then sometime you have to consider that, timed function like `setInterval` can pretty not respect the exact defined time interval. Maybe it can be more practice to give an approximative value like `985ms` instead of `1000ms`; so that you can have  a margin error.